# Prevent browser predicting input in input box

Tags: html, input

I am trying to prevent the browser giving me recommendations when I type into an input box. For example, if I type `'a'` it will give me a list of items beginning with`'a'` that I have typed into an input box in my browser in the past.

I have tried `autocomplete="false"` but this doesnt work as far as I can tell. Autocomplete must be different to what I am looking for.

Perhaps it is a browser setting that cannot be controlled by the developer. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: That is an internal feature some browsers implement. That is nothing that can be controlled or actively be used by a web page loaded into the browser. Just like you cannot access the browsers settings for very good reasons. The user can configure his own browser to _not_ make such fill in suggestions. But that is up to the user, not the the creator of some web page.

Answer (score 2):

It is working for me on this codepen link. It doesn't display prediction for email field, but it does show prediction for first name and last name field.

If it doesn't work for you then it must be your system software causing this. I'm using Chrome on Linux.

`<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>`

http://codepen.io/piyushpatel2005/pen/aJQaNN

Comment: it worked, thanks! it was a react thing. i needed to use `autoComplete`